# Cordova Media is not defined iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an iOS app using Cordova **3.4.0** and I'm trying to use the media plugin whilst developing the app, however all I'm seeing is:

`Uncaught Reference Error: Media is not defined`

Since 3.0.0 Cordova uses plugins and the documentation for the Media plugin isn't entirely clearly so I'm not sure if it's set up correctly, although I believe it is.

My config.xml reads:

```
<plugin name="Media" value="CDVSound" />
```

Has anybody encountered this error before with the media plugin and know a fix?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the Cordova CLI or Cordova PlugMan to install the Media plugin?

--edit--
After a version update, I was able to replicate your issue. It appears that the media plugin is entirely broken. I've submitted a bug report and will get back to this soon.

Your config.xml is correct for iOS audio permissions.

Here are the steps I took to install a working copy of the media plugin

```
$ cordova create bazfoo && cd bazfoo
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
$ cordova run ios
```

If you want to see it working, clone the Cordova Mobile Spec into the www/ folder with:
    $ git clone https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec www/

--edit--
on further invenstigation, I DID find that one of media's dependencies is not automatically installed: the file plugin. I had to add it manually:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

Comment: update: the dependency issue has been resolved, we just need to wait on a plugins update for the change to be visible to the cli. I am working on the second part of the issue: even with the dependency installed, Media object is undefined.